# What algorithms are available for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, optimization, algorithms

I am trying to implement a logistic regression function in c++, and not sure what algorithm to use. So far I have heard of these:

1. Newton-Raphson
2. IRLS
3. Gradient descent

Are there other algorithms available? What are their pros and cons? Is there an algorithm generally recognized as superior to the others?

Comment: Pretty much any decent optimization algorithm can work under at least some circumstances.

[Fisher scoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm#Fisher_scoring) is very widely used and is convenient.

Comment: And if you incorporate step-halving into the algorithms they usually work well.

Comment: In the context of logistic regression, Newton's method reduces to iteratively reweighted least squares.  Working this out is an excellent exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Partially answered in comments:

Pretty much any decent optimization algorithm can work under at least some circumstances. [Fisher scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm#Fisher_scoring) is very widely used and is convenient. – Glen_b

And if you incorporate step-halving into the algorithms they usually work well. – Frank Harrell

Much used is iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS), which is a reformulation of the Newton method. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384).