# Difference between robust regression and weighted regression

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust, weighted-regression, irls

In [stata, robust regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/regressionwith-statachapter-4-beyond-ols/) (rreg) uses weights proportional to the size of the residuals. Is this conceptually the same as weighted OLS (weight by 1/variance)? And both can be applied, for example, in scenarios with heteroskedasticity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same, because in weighted OLS, weights are given apriori, they are not a function of size of residuals, as in some types of robust regression.  However, there is a connecteion, as robust regression sometimes can be calculated via IRLS, iteratively reweighted least squares.  For the last, see [can you give a simple intuitive explanation of IRLS method to find the MLE of a GLM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384)

Comment: +1 which would you choose for linear regression with heteroskedasticity?