# An intuitive explanation of Reweighted Least Squares for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, irls

Here is the reference:
http://nlp.chonbuk.ac.kr/BML/slides_freda/lec7.pdf

We know that logistic regression is implemented by `Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS)`, we have the final iteration formula of parameter $\theta:$
$$\theta^{k+1} = \theta^{k} - (H^k)^{-1}g^k$$
$$\Rightarrow\theta^{k+1} = (X^TS^kX)X^TS^kz^k,$$
$$z^k \triangleq X\theta^k+(S^k)^{-1}(y - \mu^k).$$

Here I ignore the statement of  notations. From formula: $(X^TS^kX)X^TS^kz^k$ we know that it is the solution of `General Least Square` with error covariance inverse $(S^k)^{-1}.$ Since $S^k$ is diagonal. Then it degenerates as a  `Reweighted Least Squares`.

I think the conclusion is purely from the result formula, is there any intuitive explanation before we know the result formula?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384